# Is there any pattern in the sequence $125, 2518, 108, 114, \_\_\_,286,144, 3621, 105$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

One of my students came up with the following question-

Find the missing number in $125,2518,108,114,?,286,144,3621,105$.

At first, I thought it contains $3$ separate sequences viz $125,114,144,\ldots$, $2518, ?, 3621,\ldots$ and $108,286,105,\ldots$. But that does not help. I was unable to find any pattern. Then I converted them into binary, but no luck there as well.

They gave me the question in a rectangular form like -

$$125 ~~2518~~108$$
$$114~~~~~?~~~~~~286$$
$$144~~3621~~~105$$

I suspected that this is meaningless but my students said that they got it from a book and this question was also featured in a website, but the page no longer available. What is going on here? Can anybody help me find a pattern? Or is it meaningless? thanks.

Comment: I think there are too many ways to fill in the blank.  I have a logical explanation for the blank to be $114143$.  I notice that in the first row and the third row, the numbers are of the form $a\cdot n, a*b,b\cdot(n+1)$, where $*$ is concatenation.  ($a=25$, $b=18$, and $n=5$ in the first row.  $a=36$, $b=21$, and $n=4$ in the third row.)  So, if I apply the same logic, I find that the second row has $a=114$, $b=143$, and $n=1$.  But I am sure that you can find a logical way to fill in the blank with a different number.

Comment: The first thing to do with questions like this is to look it up in the OEIS. I've tried a couple of different things, came up blank. The answer is probably not in the OEIS. But at least I can say I looked in there.

Comment: My second thought was that it might be a magic square, but the full verticals are not helping...